# How to solve this Javascript/Razor prolem?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I try to add the following javascript code.

```
 <script> 
    @if (ViewBag.checkedArtikel != null)
    {
        foreach (int ac in ViewBag.checkedArtikel)
        {
            String temp = "'#addartikel" + ac + "'";
            <text> $(@temp).toggleClass('down');</text>
        }
    }
    </script>
```

If i leave out the script tag i get the right jquery commands:

```
$('#addartikel1').toggleClass('down');
```

But with the script tag i get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<text>$(@Html.Raw(temp)).toggleClass('down');</text>
```

Or you can use your old code without adding quotes to variable:

```
String temp = "#addartikel" + ac;
<text> $('@temp').toggleClass('down');</text>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have very badly mixed server side Razor code with client side javascript. Here's the correct way to do that, by using a JSON serializer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var articles = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.checkedArtikel ?? new int[0]));
    $(articles).each(function() {
        $('#addartikel' + this).toggleClass('down');
    });
</script>
```